# Tracing Mhash Files (Hashing)

Tags: c, hash, md5, trace, mhash

I am trying to trace how this open source program, mhash computes it's hashing

I can run the program successfully by using using the following commands:

gcc -o example example.c -lmhash

(also, mhash is currently installed, and I am running Ubuntu Linux)

Mhash can be found here: http://mhash.sourceforge.net/

and the example that I have tried is here:

```
#include <mhash.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char password[] = "Jefe";
    int keylen = 4;
    char data[] = "what do ya want for nothing?";
    int datalen = 28;
    MHASH td;
    unsigned char *mac;
    int j;

    td = mhash_hmac_init(MHASH_MD5, password, keylen,
                            mhash_get_hash_pblock(MHASH_MD5));
    mhash(td, data, datalen);
    mac = mhash_hmac_end(td);
    /* 
     * The output should be 0x750c783e6ab0b503eaa86e310a5db738
     * according to RFC 2104.
     */
    printf("0x");
    for (j = 0; j < mhash_get_block_size(MHASH_MD5); j++) {
        printf("%.2x", mac[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    exit(0);
}
```

I have read the API's, it has very well documentations, but there are soo many files, I do not know from which areas it inherits it's algorithms from?

Thanks for your time and help in advance

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems a little vague to me ... I'm not sure I fully understand it. I'll adventure myself into an answer though.

If you simply don't know what gets executed for crunching that `MD5` hash the easiest way to get into it is probably to attach yourself with a debugger on this example program of yours. Make sure you have the debug flags enabled on your `mhash` library (which seem to be on by default), then step in `mhash` and see where that gets you. You cannot miss anything this way.

In gdb it would look something like this (You'd probably want to use an IDE - eclipse perhaps, to make it a LOT prettier):

```
$ gdb ./test.exe
..
Reading symbols from /home/B41655/workspace/ctest/test.exe...done.
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4011af: file test.c, line 5.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/B41655/workspace/ctest/test.exe
[New Thread 10200.0x205c]
[New Thread 10200.0x27b0]

Breakpoint 1, main () at test.c:5
5               char password[] = "Jefe";
(gdb) s
6               int keylen = 4;
(gdb) s
7               char data[] = "what do ya want for nothing?";
(gdb) s
8               int datalen = 28;
(gdb) s
13              td = mhash_hmac_init(MHASH_MD5, password, keylen,
(gdb) s
mhash_get_hash_pblock (type=MHASH_MD5) at mhash.c:438
438     {
(gdb) s
441             MHASH_ALG_LOOP(ret = p->hash_pblock);
```

and so on ...

If by any chance you want to passively get some sort a call graph of your `example` program execution you could do that with a profiler. Using `gprof` on this program would issue something like this (this would require your library/program recompiled with -pg flag):

```
index % time    self  children    called     name
                0.00    0.00      17/17          main [81]
 [2]     0.0    0.00    0.00      17         mhash_get_block_size [2]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00       1/9           mhash [14]
                0.00    0.00       2/9           mhash_hmac_deinit [17]
                0.00    0.00       2/9           mhash_hmac_init [20]
                0.00    0.00       2/9           MD5Update [9]
                0.00    0.00       2/9           MD5Final [10]
[3]      0.0    0.00    0.00       9         mutils_memcpy [3]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00       1/6           mhash_deinit [15]
                0.00    0.00       1/6           mhash_hmac_init [20]
                0.00    0.00       2/6           mhash_hmac_deinit [17]
                0.00    0.00       2/6           MD5Final [10]
[4]      0.0    0.00    0.00       6         mutils_bzero [4]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00       1/6           mhash_hmac_end_m [19]
                0.00    0.00       1/6           mhash_hmac_init [20]
                0.00    0.00       4/6           mhash_init_int [12]
[5]      0.0    0.00    0.00       6         mutils_malloc [5]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00       2/6           MD5Update [9]
                0.00    0.00       4/6           MD5Final [10]
[6]      0.0    0.00    0.00       6         mutils_word32nswap [6]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00       1/5           mhash_deinit [15]
                0.00    0.00       4/5           mhash_hmac_deinit [17]
[7]      0.0    0.00    0.00       5         mutils_free [7]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00       2/4           MD5Update [9]
                0.00    0.00       2/4           MD5Final [10]
[8]      0.0    0.00    0.00       4         MD5Transform [8]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00       1/4           mhash [14]
                0.00    0.00       1/4           mhash_hmac_init [20]
                0.00    0.00       2/4           mhash_hmac_deinit [17]
[9]      0.0    0.00    0.00       4         MD5Update [9]
                0.00    0.00       2/9           mutils_memcpy [3]
                0.00    0.00       2/6           mutils_word32nswap [6]
                0.00    0.00       2/4           MD5Transform [8]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00       1/2           mhash_deinit [15]
                0.00    0.00       1/2           mhash_hmac_deinit [17]
[10]     0.0    0.00    0.00       2         MD5Final [10]
                0.00    0.00       4/6           mutils_word32nswap [6]
                0.00    0.00       2/4           MD5Transform [8]
                0.00    0.00       2/9           mutils_memcpy [3]
                0.00    0.00       2/6           mutils_bzero [4]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00       2/2           mhash_init_int [12]
[11]     0.0    0.00    0.00       2         MD5Init [11]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00       1/2           mhash_hmac_deinit [17]
                0.00    0.00       1/2           mhash_hmac_init [20]
[12]     0.0    0.00    0.00       2         mhash_init_int [12]
                0.00    0.00       4/6           mutils_malloc [5]
                0.00    0.00       2/2           mutils_memset [13]
                0.00    0.00       2/2           MD5Init [11]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00       2/2           mhash_init_int [12]
[13]     0.0    0.00    0.00       2         mutils_memset [13]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00       1/1           main [81]
[14]     0.0    0.00    0.00       1         mhash [14]
                0.00    0.00       1/9           mutils_memcpy [3]
                0.00    0.00       1/4           MD5Update [9]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00       1/1           mhash_hmac_deinit [17]
[15]     0.0    0.00    0.00       1         mhash_deinit [15]
                0.00    0.00       1/6           mutils_bzero [4]
                0.00    0.00       1/2           MD5Final [10]
                0.00    0.00       1/5           mutils_free [7]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00       1/1           main [81]
[16]     0.0    0.00    0.00       1         mhash_get_hash_pblock [16]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00       1/1           mhash_hmac_end_m [19]
[17]     0.0    0.00    0.00       1         mhash_hmac_deinit [17]
                0.00    0.00       4/5           mutils_free [7]
                0.00    0.00       2/9           mutils_memcpy [3]
                0.00    0.00       2/4           MD5Update [9]
                0.00    0.00       2/6           mutils_bzero [4]
                0.00    0.00       1/2           mhash_init_int [12]
                0.00    0.00       1/2           MD5Final [10]
                0.00    0.00       1/1           mhash_deinit [15]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00       1/1           main [81]
[18]     0.0    0.00    0.00       1         mhash_hmac_end [18]
                0.00    0.00       1/1           mhash_hmac_end_m [19]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00       1/1           mhash_hmac_end [18]
[19]     0.0    0.00    0.00       1         mhash_hmac_end_m [19]
                0.00    0.00       1/6           mutils_malloc [5]
                0.00    0.00       1/1           mhash_hmac_deinit [17]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00       1/1           main [81]
[20]     0.0    0.00    0.00       1         mhash_hmac_init [20]
                0.00    0.00       2/9           mutils_memcpy [3]
                0.00    0.00       1/2           mhash_init_int [12]
                0.00    0.00       1/6           mutils_malloc [5]
                0.00    0.00       1/6           mutils_bzero [4]
                0.00    0.00       1/4           MD5Update [9]
-----------------------------------------------
```

showing you which functions got executed and how they were called.

Comment: Wow this is really great information, thanks. My question was a little vague, I was just trying to figure out how it actually compiled the program because it had soo many .h's. I am also new to C programming and I just use gcc for compiling. I thought Eclipse was an IDE for high level languages?

Comment: Eclipse is a plugin-based framework. There's an eclipse plugin nowadays for pretty much any language/development technology out there. See the C development suite: http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/